# How to download a file from a URL using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, download, webclient

I want to download a .xlsx file from below address.
http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=1396-08-08

by clicking on the link automatically a file will be downloaded by the browser. I tried to download the file from this codes:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
      client.DownloadFile("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=1396-08-08", @"D:\Archive\1396-08-08.xlsx");
}
```

But it will download a weird file different from the file downloaded by the browser at first step.

Also I tried :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0");
```

But this code has two disadvantages:

1- It opens a browser which is not required.

2- I can't determine any path or file name for the downloaded file.

I want to gain exactly the same file that will be downloaded by clicking on the above link address. 
How can I download my required file?

[image: Currupted file]
[image: Correct File]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen is correct. Your browser is smart enough to decompress the file because the response contains the header:

```
content-encoding:"gzip"
```

You can download and decompress the file with this code (adjust accordingly for your file name, path, etc.)

```
void Main()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");
        byte[] filedata = client.DownloadData("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=1396-08-08");

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(filedata))
        {    
            using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create("c:\\deleteme\\test.xlsx"))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```