# There is one Url for DownLoad Excel.When I paste that url in browser it downloads.But in C# it is not Working

Tags: c#

There is one Url  for DownLoad Excel.When I paste that url in browser it downloads.But when I use C# WebClient.DownLoadFile(source,Destination),It does not download.)

Comment: I followed following url ,still not working.I am getting following exception.Exception: The magic number in GZip header is not correct.

Comment: You can change question, add additional info to it. Need more details, what .net you use?

Answer (score -1):

Well, showing more lines of codes will make solving your problem super fast.

However, you can try this

Using the [WebClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFile_System_String_System_String_)

```
using System.Net;
//...
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
var address = "http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png";
var destination = @"C:\folder\stackoverflowlogo.png";
Client.DownloadFile(address, destination);
```

Edited: I noticed you're using credentials. Try this,

```
Uri ur = new Uri("http://remotehost.do/images/img.jpg");

using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username" + ":" + "MyNewPassword"));
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";

    client.DownloadProgress += WebClientDownloadProgress;
    client.DownloadDataDone += WebClientDownloadDone;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, @"C:\path\newImage.jpg");
}
```

Implement the functions:

```
void WebClientDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);

    // updating the UI or do something else
}

void WebClientDownloadDone(object sender, DownloadDataDoneEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
}
```

In summary, this might not be exactly what you want to do, but it gives you an idea of to use the authorizations. Happy coding!

Comment: I used similar code.It is not working.By this it creates the excel file but that does not open.It shows it is corrupted or format is not correct.

Comment: Show me what you have done in code and also the URL you're using.

Comment: @PatNadis this is what the user is already using, how's this any different?

Comment: using(WebClient wc=new WebClient()){wc.UseDefaultCredentials= true;wc.DownLoadFile(source url,destination url);}

Comment: @zaggler since he didn't show up how is using it, and also the URL to check if he is doing things in a correct way.

Comment: @PatNadis "when I use" -> `WebClient.DownLoadFile(source,Destination)`...

Comment: @ratikantarout can you paste your code in full?

Comment: I can not paste code,since it is banking application.I using same what I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Pat Nadis My problem is similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095791/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Pat Nadis After following this url ,I am getting  Exception: The magic number in GZip header is not correct.

Comment: @ratikantarout The code that downloads the file is the code that downloads the file, there is nothing secret in it. Remove sensitive info and show what you use for download, and what `.net` version you use?

Comment: Mb you are looking for something like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/21901efe-8d36-40ed-9dad-2ce9968b4273/the-magic-number-in-gzip-header-is-not-correct-error?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Genusatplay I am using dotnet 4.0 version.